A RenderFlex overflowed by 41 pixels on the right

I am Getting Error when I am using Row === A RenderFlex overflowed by 41 pixels on the right.
I am trying to add A Text inside AppBar in left side but I am not getting proper output it’s giving me error === A RenderFlex overflowed by 41 pixels on the right.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

By default, the value of AppBar. leadingWidth is 56.0
Documentation of AppBar
Do below changes in AppBar to increase width of leading widget
AppBar(
title: const Text('Contact'),
 leading: Placeholder(color: Colors.white),
 leadingWidth: 100,
)


use title property instead of leading
AppBar(title: const Text('Contact')),
if you need to align it center then you can just use centerTitle: true,
commonly leading is used for adding icons for back button or drawer
